# Find ports locked to process running in the background

Tags: bash, process

Is it possible to find the ports assigned to the process started on the background?

I want to start a process and let it run in the background, like `./run.sh &` and then see all the ports this process is using.

This process might start other processes, so I'd like to see all ports locked by this process and any children.

Is it possible?

Comment: If I understand you correctly - netstat -nap may help you. And maybe a little script to find all child processes for your initial process, and then to search for network ports used by these (if any).

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. You could use `netstat -a | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'`

Comment: It didn't work for me. I started a brand new terminal and without starting the `run.sh` I ran your script and it showed processes. Since I hadn't ran the process it should return nothing, no?

Comment: netstat will return all processes. The `| egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'` is only filtering out processes that are not directly attached to a port. You could replace it with this line `netstat -a | egrep 'run'` or replace run with whatever service you're looking for.

Comment: ok, but how do I filter it based on the pid of the process running in the background and its children?

Comment: To get the pid included in netstat use the `-p` switch.

`netstat -ap | egrep '2134'`

Be sure to replace the '2134' with the pid you're actually searching for.